# How use table column as string in a multi-table update in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Two tables,

```
agent(agent_id, agent_real_name, .....)
blog(blog_id, blog_agent_id, blog_name, ...)
```

Now I want to set the blog_name as agent_real_name + "'s blog"
I used following SQL sentence but failed,

```
update blog, agent set blog_name = agent_real_name '\'s blog' where agent_id = 31
```

PS: 31 is the id of a agent

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use:
 `update blog, agent set blog_name = concat(agent_real_name, '\'s blog') where agent_id = 31`

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE blog b INNER JOIN agent a
ON a.agent_id = b.blog_agent_id
SET b.blog_name = CONCAT(a.agent_real_name,'\'s blog') 
WHERE a.agent_id = 31
```